# Save EA diagram with transparent background

Tags: enterprise-architect

How do we specify the background color (or transparency) for exported images?

We are trying to export a diagram from EA 14 to PowerPoint and when we do it is always a large white box. We'd like the background to be transparent so we can place it on a rectangle filled with one of the theme colors. It would even be acceptable to use the current gradient fill in a frame, but it always exports a frame filled with white.

Comment: Can you export to svg? Or copy-paste to inkscape?

Comment: That is basically what I'm doing now, export the PNG, add a transparent layer and erase all the white; very manual.

Comment: There is an svg export add-in available somewhere. Never really used it myself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple and sad: you can't. While transparency seems to be partly supported with images (after many, many years) you can not export it with transparency.

Try sending a feature request. But don't hold your breath.

Not really a suggestion: use white board mode and delete the white parts with Gimp (or something like that).

Comment: I was afraid of that. (Well, afraid is a little strong, more like pessimistically expecting.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround.

1. Go into Swimlanes.
2. Add a single vertical swimlane, name is arbitrary.
3. Set its Back Color as desired.
4. Set the Line Color in Details to the same color.
5. In Details, check Hide Names.
6. After exiting Swimlanes, resize the single swimlane so it acts as the background.

When the diagram is saved or copied, it takes the background with it. A little downside: You will have to resize the swimlane if the width of the active area of the diagram changes.